# Operations on a heap

Tags: c++, c++17, heap

### Introduction

I started going through some basic algorithms as I'll have algorithms course next semester. The last time I've written any heap operations is around 5 years ago. This time around it took me an hour to debug the case where the right child wouldn't exist, but left child did. Otherwise it was straightforward.

The code below implements four basic operations on a heap:

- Push (sift down)
- Pop (swap with the last element and then perform push on truncated heap)
- Build heap (push one by one starting from the middle, achieving linear complexity)
- Sort heap (continuosly pop elements and truncate the heap, pushing greater elements to the end of the underlying container)

The code works on iterator ranges, requires `RandomAccessIterator`, `Swappable` value types of the iterator type.

### Code

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <unordered_set>
#include <numeric>
#include <algorithm>

std::vector<int> generate_vector(std::size_t size)
{
    if (size == 0)
        return {};
    if (size == 1)
        return {0};

    static std::mt19937 twister{};
    std::vector<int> numbers(size);
    std::iota(numbers.begin(), numbers.end(), 0);
    std::shuffle(numbers.begin(), numbers.end(), twister);

    return numbers;
}

#include <iterator>

namespace shino
{
    template <typename RandomAccessIterator>
    void push_heap(RandomAccessIterator first,
                   RandomAccessIterator last,
                   RandomAccessIterator element)
    {
        auto dist = std::distance(first, element) + 1;
        auto left_child = first + dist * 2 - 1;
        if (left_child >= last)
            return;
        auto right_child = first + dist * 2;
        if (right_child >= last)
        {
            if (*element < *left_child)
            {
                std::iter_swap(element, left_child);
                push_heap(first, last, left_child);
            }
            return;
        }

        if (*element >= *left_child and *element >= *right_child)
            return;

        auto next_location =
                (*left_child >= *right_child) ? left_child : right_child;
        std::iter_swap(next_location, element);
        shino::push_heap(first, last, next_location);
    }

    template <typename RandomAccessIterator>
    void build_heap(RandomAccessIterator first, RandomAccessIterator last)
    {
        for (auto middle = first + std::distance(first, last) / 2;
             middle != first; --middle)
        {
            shino::push_heap(first, last, middle);
        }

        shino::push_heap(first, last, first);
    }

    template <typename RandomAccessIterator>
    void pop_heap(RandomAccessIterator first, RandomAccessIterator last)
    {
        if (std::distance(first, last) < 2)
            return;

        auto new_last = std::prev(last);
        std::iter_swap(first, new_last);
        shino::push_heap(first, new_last, first);
    }

    template <typename RandomAccessIterator>
    void sort_heap(RandomAccessIterator first, RandomAccessIterator last)
    {
        auto current_last = last;
        while (first != current_last)
        {
            shino::pop_heap(first, current_last);
            --current_last;
        }
    }
}

#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i <= 10'000; ++i)
    {
        std::vector<int> v(generate_vector(i));

        std::cout << "heapifying vector of size " << i << '\n';
        shino::build_heap(v.begin(), v.end());
        if (not std::is_heap(v.begin(), v.end()))
            std::cerr << "incorrect heapifying on size " << i << '\n';

        shino::sort_heap(v.begin(), v.end());
        if (not std::is_sorted(v.begin(), v.end()))
            std::cerr << "incorrect heap sorting on size " << i << '\n';
    }
}
```

---

### Concerns

- `push_heap` looks very ugly

  The control flow is so obfuscated and hard to follow. I couldn't make it better though.
- Indexing looks ugly too

  One of the weakest point of iterators: algorithms where indexing is important. Is there a way to make it better?
- Anything else

Comment: Did you spot a bug? I had the feeling that something is wrong, but tests were silent. If there is something wrong with the post, it would be great to get a feedback so I could fix it.

Comment: What class are you taking?

Comment: @JDługosz, it’s in my university. I can’t recall the exact name, but it is something similar to intro to algorithms

Comment: What level?  If you already studied them 5 years ago, and you can write that now, you hardly need an “intro”!

Comment: @JDługosz, those were dark times. In fact, until Loki (aka Martin York) got me onboard of this site, I was quite dumb. I still am, just a little bit less. I was one of those diehard competitive programming guys.

Comment: To whoever is voting to close this question: please clarify what should be improved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you know what you’re doing.

One thing I spotted:  Don’t write `std::iter_swap` quallified like that.  You have to use ADL to pick up the right version provided for the template arguments.  You need the “two step”:

```
using std::iter_swap;
iter_swap (a,b);
```

just like with regular `swap`.

---

You don’t need to qualify your own names when you are in that namespace.  Or is that intentional to guard against ADL?  I never see that technique used.

---

Check out [Catch2](https://github.com/catchorg/Catch2) for beefing up your `main` into a comprehensive unit test.

---

`generate_vector` is missing out on NVRO due to your precondition tests.  Declare `numbers` at the top; always return that.

Comment: Qualified names and some other weird things are artifacts from multiple improvement iterations (at the start it wasn’t even a template and it lacked namespace). Thanks for Catch2, I’ve heard positive things about it, except compilation times.

Comment: Putting `CATCH_CONFIG_MAIN` in a separate CPP file that never changes makes the compilation time OK.  My current project takes 1.4 seconds for optimized build.

Comment: that looks nice. I’ll give it a shot tomorrow.

Comment: I've never seen `iter_swap` used as a customization point, so qualifying it looks perfectly reasonable to me.

Comment: @Rakete1111  I wonder why they would bother with defining a function where using it is longer than not using it (`swap(*a,*b)` vs `iter_swap(a,b)`) unless it was there to abstract something, like a special optimal way of swapping when using a specific kind of iterator.  What else would it be for?

Comment: @JDługosz see https://stackoverflow.com/q/13991909/3980929

Comment: @Rakete1111 I think the SGI documentation is out of date.  `vector<bool>` returns a proxy.  I suppose that the correct customization would be to define a `swap` for your proxy return classes; ⋯ (reading Slack) ⋯ it *is used* in Qt for more efficient swapping than actually swapping the elements.

Comment: @JDługosz Ooh interesting. Thanks for the info!

Comment: So I would still offer the advice:  if you bother using `iter_swap` instead of `swap(*,*)`, use it *just like swap* so that it will pick up any efficiency gain offered.

Answer (score 3):

List all your `#include` directives at the top of the file.  Then you'd see that you `#include <algorithm>` twice.

Comment: Does it effect compile time too much? I mean, I know the practice has always been redundant.

Comment: @AniketChowdhury It will have a very small (possibly minimal) effect on compile time.  The exact amount will depend on how that header is implemented.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm, I believe that is an artifact from a debugging session. I spent considerable time on finding a bug in the `shino::push_heap()`.